# why function(){}.__proto__ === Function.prototype and Function.prototype === function(){}.__proto_ return different result

Tags: javascript, prototype

`function(){}.__proto__ === Function.prototype` and `Function.prototype === function(){}.__proto__` get different result

`Function.prototype === function(){}.__proto__` return `true`.

`function(){}.__proto__ === Function.prototype` return an error:

> VM2053:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name

Comment: Wrap it with parentesis to make it an expression `(function(){}).__proto__ === Function.prototype`

Comment: yes，when wrap it with parentesis ,it`s ok.  i don`t understand is there any different put `function(){}` in the `===` left or right?

Comment: `function` in the beginning is function declaration statement. Try `function a(){}.__proto__` Almost the same as `[] === {}` vs `{} === []` where `{}` is not an object literal but a block statement when appears in the beginning.

Comment: So `function(){}.__proto__ === Function.prototype` effetively means `function(){}; .__proto__ === Function.prototype;` notice `;`

Comment: o, i see, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. You could also use [ast explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/51fab4c0ed6fe2484b967402aaecd5b5/05534541037c8c3fef53d674f78a32a46a2f1bbf) with say tsc parser (that wont bail on the first error) to check how the code is parsed.

Comment: @yury would make sense to add that as an answer, wouldn't it ...?

Answer (score 3):

Because function declarations must have a name, where as function expressions do not. From the wiki page on [Immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression), in the case where the line starts with `function`:

> when the parser encounters the function keyword, it treats it as a function declaration (statement), and not as a function expression.

Comment: This is definitely the case. The first situation is interpreted as an expression, while the second is interpreted as a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`(function () {}).__proto__ === Function.prototype` return true.

`Function.prototype === (function () {}).__proto__` also return true;

Comment: This question is about why one of them throws an error